# React with docker on MacOS doesn't connect to the backend microservices

Tags: reactjs, docker, docker-compose, frontend, backend

I am trying to fully switch my react app from windows to macOs. However this time I am using docker to compile and fully boot up my react app (problems with the depencies otherwise). Everything works as it should, however for some reasons, my react app doesn't connect to the backend... The backend are microservices which get boot up with docker-compose, in particular there is one main microservice which is the http-proxy, that kinda handles all the other, in fact that the one that gets attached and connected to the front end. How come on windows I could connect to the backend without any issues, and now that I am on mac and using docker, those things dont work?

here is the dockerfile (react app):

```
FROM node:16.20.0-alpine
# Install git
RUN apk update && apk add git
# Create app directory
WORKDIR /Users/lucagirotti/Documents/TNO/lumos
# Install app dependencies
# A wildcard is used to ensure both package.json AND package-lock.json are copied
# where available (npm@5+)
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install --force
#To bundle your app’s source code inside the Docker image, use the COPY instruction:
COPY . .
#Your app binds to port 3000 so you’ll use the EXPOSE instruction to have it mapped by the docker daemon:
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

and this is the docker-compose.yaml (backend):

```
version: '3'

services:

  http-proxy:
    image: nginx:1.23-alpine
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - internal
    ports:
      - 8443:443
    volumes:
      - ./provisioning/proxy/certificates:/etc/nginx/certificates
      - ./provisioning/proxy/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    depends_on:
      - frontend-lobby
      - frontend-client
      - socketio-nats-proxy
      - scene-controller

  nats:
    image: nats:2.3-alpine
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - internal
    ports:
      - 4222:4222 # Main messaging
      - 8222:8222 # Monitoring

  mongodb:
    image: bitnami/mongodb:4.4.15
    restart: always
    networks:
      - internal
    volumes:
      - mongodb:/bitnami/mongodb
      - ./provisioning/mongodb/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/:ro
    environment:
      # Databases and users are created in ./docker-entrypoint.initdb.d/mongo-init.js
      MONGODB_INITIAL_PRIMARY_PORT_NUMBER: 27017

  nats-logger:
    image: ci.tno.nl/socialxr/services/nats-logger:master
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - internal
    depends_on:
      - nats
    environment:
      NATS_ADDRESS: nats:4222

  frontend-lobby:
    image: ci.tno.nl/vrtogether/togethervr2:feature-nats-backend-lobby
    networks:
      - internal

  frontend-client:
    image: ci.tno.nl/vrtogether/togethervr2:feature-nats-backend-client
    networks:
      - internal

  socketio-nats-proxy:
    image: ci.tno.nl/socialxr/socketio-nats-proxy:master
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - internal
    depends_on:
      - nats
    environment:
      NATS_ADDRESS: nats:4222
      PORT: 8080 # Port within the container.

  session-controller:
    image: ci.tno.nl/socialxr/services/session-controller:master
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - internal
    depends_on:
      - nats
      - mongodb
    environment:
      NATS_ADDRESS: nats:4222
      STORAGE_URI: mongodb://u-sec:pw@mongodb:27017/session-controller?replicaSet=socialxrlab

  scene-controller:
    image: ci.tno.nl/socialxr/services/scene-controller:master
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - internal
    depends_on:
      - nats
    environment:
      NATS_ADDRESS: nats:4222
      HTTP_PORT: 8080

  media-controller-manager:
    image: ci.tno.nl/socialxr/services/media-controller-manager:master
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - internal
    depends_on:
      - nats
    environment:
      NATS_ADDRESS: nats:4222

  p2p-media-controller:
    image: ci.tno.nl/socialxr/services/p2p-media-controller:master
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - internal
    depends_on:
      - nats
      - mongodb
    environment:
      NATS_ADDRESS: nats:4222
      STORAGE_URI: mongodb://u-p2pmc:pw@mongodb:27017/p2p-media-controller?replicaSet=socialxrlab


volumes:
  mongodb:

networks:
  internal:
```

Comment: Since today also my nats client didn't connect in MacOS. My connection string was "nats://localhost:4222". After I've changed to "nats://127.0.0.1:4222" it works with docker as well with standalone server.

Comment: @Rancid, ok so I have changed the url for connecting to the backend, with 127.0.0.1, however nothing, still doesnt connect/gets linked with it...

Comment: I suggest you to check each piece of your components individually. Be careful with the HOST_PORT and CONTAINER_PORT you set on docker-compose. To test locally you will need to use HOST_PORT to connect to the service specified with CONTAINER_PORT. The components, among themselves, use CONTAINER PORT (https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/).

Comment: @Rancid ok so in this case what are you suggesting? What should I change and to which url should I connect the frontend with the backend?

Comment: I suggest you to check each piece of your components individually. For every component check if it runs, what ports uses, if the port is reachable, and so on. Check if the components connects with each other, piece by piece, port by port. In this way you can find what connection doesn't works. For example: in my case the nats client didn't connect with "localhost". I've tried to simplify and I've seen that  127.0.0.1 works, so the issue was the DNS translation.

Comment: they all seem to be running, but still though, somehow I really dont get why this is not connecting properly... @Rancid